# Missing Assembly Reference Using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.13.9 with Azure KeyVault C# SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure, nuget, azure-keyvault

For some reason, I have to latest `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` [v3.13.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory) with `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault` [v2.0.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault). And it always throws exceptions for missing assembly reference, but downgrading `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` to v2.28.4, which I'm not allowed to use, can resolve this [known issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/511).

Here's the exception:

```
  InnerException:
   HResult=-2146233036
   Message=The type initializer for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformPlugin' threw an exception.
   Source=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
   TypeName=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformPlugin
   StackTrace:
        at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformPlugin.get_Logger()
        at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext..cctor()
   InnerException:
        ErrorCode=assembly_not_found
        HResult=-2146233088
        Message=Assembly required for the platform not found. Make sure assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform, Version=3.12.0.827, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' exists
        Source=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
        StackTrace:
             at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformPlugin.LoadPlatformSpecificAssembly()
             at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformPlugin.InitializeByAssemblyDynamicLinking()
             at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformPlugin..cctor()
        InnerException:
             FileName=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform, Version=3.12.0.827, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
             FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
```

Code snippets:

```
    protected KeyVaultBase(string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientId));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientSecret));
        }

        this.KeyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
            new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                (authority, resource, scope) => GetAccessToken(authority, resource, scope, clientId, clientSecret)
            )
        );
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var authnContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        var result = await authnContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

The exception throws while executing `var authnContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);`.

Does anyone know any solution/workaround to resolve this issue without the downgrading?

Comment: what version of .net framework is  your current project building under when you right click on the project and select properties..?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: are you allowed to change the project to use a different version of .net framework for example down to 4.0 what you could also do is change the dll in the reference node for the `CopytoLocal=` value from false to true

Comment: No. My team mostly use .NET 4.5 and 4.5.2.

Comment: then can this be GAC'd? it almost sounds like a GAC issue..

Comment: so...any solutions?

Comment: is the dll in the GAC..? or is the dll reference added to the References node in the project..? if so ..then click on that .dll and see if the CopyLocal= property is set to `CopyLocal=true`

Comment: both `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` and `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform` are set to Copy Local = True.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the `references` were installed only to the `class library project`, not to the executing `assembly`, so it was throwing this exception.

Adding the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` nuget package to the executing assembly worked for me.

Hope it helps

Comment: YES! This answered worked for me and saved me hours. I was using the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` version 3.19 in a class library project but only had version 2.22 installed in the actual ASP.NET Web Application project. Upgrading to 3.19 in the web app project got me past the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try **uninstall** both of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v3.13.9 and Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault v2.0.6 then **reinstall** them again. If there are multiple projects in the solution are referenced them, please make sure all of the them are the same version.

I create a console or Asp.net MVC project, both are working correctly on my side using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v3.13.9 with Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault v2.0.6.

The following is my detail steps:

1.Create a C# console project.

2.Add the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v3.13.9 with nuget.

3.Add the Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault v2.0.6 from Package manager console with command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault -Version 2.0.6
```

Packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" version="2.0.6" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.WebKey" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.13.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Add a class in the project:

```
 class KeyVaultBase
    {

        static string _clientId= "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        static string _clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        static string _tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string azureTenantId, string azureAppId, string azureSecretKey)
        {

            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + _tenantId);
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_clientId, _clientSecret);
            var tokenResponse = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net", clientCredential);
            var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
            return accessToken;
        }

    }
```

4.Test Get Secret from the KeyVault

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(KeyVaultBase.GetAccessToken));
            string secretUri = "https://KeyVaultNameSpace.vault.azure.net/secrets/secretsname/6341322679db4f3491814ff6178dee45";
            var sec = kv.GetSecretAsync(secretUri).Result;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Still doesn't work. I'll ping you on Skype tomorrow, and share you my testing project.

Comment: Do you have a try to create a new project?

Comment: Actually two testing projects -- one works as Library, the other is a Console app. Btw, I use Azure Mooncake.

Comment: Sorry, I gave up on this method. I'll contact you offline later today.